# Finding words in a string

Tags: php, strpos

Can anyone suggest how I would do this: Say if I had the string `$text` which holds text entered by a user. I want to use an 'if statement' to find if the string contains one of the words `$word1` `$word2` or `$word3` . Then if it doesn't, allow me to run some code.

```
if ( strpos($string, '@word1' OR '@word2' OR '@word3') == false ) {
    // Do things here.
}
```

I need something like that.

Comment: You want to run if all of them are absent, or atleast one of them is absent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - If string contains one of these words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966490/php-if-string-contains-one-of-these-words)

Comment: @Joey Morani: Please don't duplicate questions.

Comment: Really sorry. The last question I made a mistake, so please if a mod could close/delete the last one. This one is much more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More flexibile way is to use array of words:

```
$text = "Some text that containts word1";    
$words = array("word1", "word2", "word3");

$exists = false;
foreach($words as $word) {
    if(strpos($text, $word) !== false) {
        $exists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($exists) {
    echo $word ." exists in text";
} else {
    echo $word ." not exists in text";
}
```

Result is: word1 exists in text

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( strpos($string, $word1) === false && strpos($string, $word2) === false && strpos($string, $word3) === false) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the following function:

```
function check_sentence($str) {
  $words = array('word1','word2','word3');

  foreach($words as $word)
  {
    if(strpos($str, $word) > 0) {
    return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

And invoke it like this:

```
if(!check_sentence("what does word1 mean?"))
{
  //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966490/php-if-string-contains-one-of-these-words/6966526#6966526):

```
if ($string === str_replace(array('@word1', '@word2', '@word3'), '', $string))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use `stripos` instead of `strpos` because it is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use preg_match, like this

```
if (preg_match("/($word1)|($word2)|($word3)/", $string) === 0) {
       //do something
}
```